# Parent Child Relationship UI

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, user-interface

Consider the following Parent/Child relationship.  What I would like to know is how I would go about creating a GUI for this with the following requirements:

1. All Parents or children will contain an image a label and a couple of buttons
2. Parents will be collapse able
3. New Parents/Children can be added at any time

I was thinking about using an ItemsControl but am unsure how I would get the nesting to work correctly.

```
Parent 1  
|-Parent 2  
|-Parent 3  
|--P3 Child 1  
|--P3 Child 2  
|--P3 Child 3  
|---P3 C3 Child 1  
|---P3 C3 Child 2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.aspx) seems like the most obvious control for this. It allows you to have nested items, and easy parent and child relationships.

Comment: Will it allow me to have mutiple controls contained within a treenode i.e. Image Label 2 buttons?

Pardon my ignorance I am fairly new to WPF

Comment: Yes, it will, no problem.  Check out the ItemTemplate property.